# Cannot compile Boost with codeblocks

Tags: c++, testing, boost

I've tried to compile this header:

```
# include < boost/test/unit_test.hpp >
```

with gcc 4.6.1 but I'm getting following (3) errors:
...\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\test\unit_test_log.hpp|131|**undefined reference to `vtable for boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t'|**
How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you actually build Boost itself..?

Comment: @smallB gcc is for C, use g++ for c++ whatever the version is

Comment: Geoffroy I'm using: mingw32-gcc-4.6.1.exe - is that wrong compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-lboost_unit_test_framework` to your compile command line

Comment: Read Section "1.11.13 Including libraries" of CodeBlock's user manual http://www.codeblocks.org/user-manual

Comment: read it, and did everything what they said, yet I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: there seems to be problem during linking phase: Linking console executable: bin\Debug\testing.exe, after this I'm getting those errors

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [single-header variant of UTF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/usage-variants/single-header-variant.html) you don't have to link a library.

Comment: much simpler solution!